# Twitter login via firebase authentication in android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate Twitter login using Firebase Authentication. I have followed the document properly . But i am getting the below error. Can anyone help me out with this.

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthWebException: There was an internal error in the web widget. [ {"code":"auth/invalid-credential","message":"Error getting request token: 401 {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}. Return to: https://bimatri-1293.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler"} ]

```
 public void initTwitter() {
    provider = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("twitter.com");
    provider.addCustomParameter("lang", "en");


}

 public void connectTwitter() {

    Task<AuthResult> pendingResultTask = mAuth.getPendingAuthResult();
    if (pendingResultTask != null) {
        // There's something already here! Finish the sign-in for your user.
        pendingResultTask
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                fetchDataFromFirebase();
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                TraceUtils.logEr("The profile--- ",e.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
    } else {
        mAuth
                .startActivityForSignInWithProvider(mActivity, provider.build())
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                fetchDataFromFirebase();
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                // Handle failure.
                                TraceUtils.logEr("The profile startActivityForSignInWithProvider --- ",e.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
    }


}

 public void disConnectTwitter() {
    // Twitter sign out
    mAuth.signOut();

}
```

Comment: Your question should show the code (a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)) that doesn't work the way you expect. Without that, it's highly unlikely that you'll get good feedback on what's wrong and how to fix it. We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves with the instructions you provide.

Comment: i have followed this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/twitter-login

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: You should still show what you've done.  We can't tell if you might have done something wrong.  If you don't show your code along with your debugging details, [the question is likely to be closed](https://overflow.tips/why-question-closed). I suggest reviewing this [checklist for asking a good question](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/checklist).

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated my question and have mentioned what i am doing. First i am OAuthProvider. Then calling disConnect method before calling the connectTwitter method

Comment: @imimobilepvt any luck fixing it?